# Something wrong with my second else statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<?php
    $check = array ("85.49.","85.62.");

    foreach($check as $var) {
        if (ereg($var, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
            $intruder = 0; 
        }
        else {
            $intruder = 1;
        }
        if ($intruder = 0);
            echo 'bugger off';
        }
        else{
            echo 'welcome';
        }
?>
```

What could be wrong with my second else? Dreamweaver red flags it and my server says error. All I want to do is get it to behave one way or another if $intruder is 1 or 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($intruder = 0);
```

First, you have an extra semicolon, so the body of the `if` statement is empty.

Secondly, `=` is assignment, you need comparison: `==`.

The structure is not clear, but probably the next problem is your loop, which will overwrite `$intruder` in each iteration, so at the end it will contain the result of the last comparison.

Comment: Extra semicolon where? If I erase the one at if ($intruder == 0); I get no changes. And I'm adding an extra =. If I erase the one after bugger off, the error in dreamweaver goes up one line to line 13.

Comment: because your loop is not closed `}`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you ask about is on this line:

```
if ($intruder = 0);
```

You should be using `==` to compare the values, not `=` which is for assignment. And you should have a curly brace `{` after that instead of a semicolon.

Also, all of the `ereg*` functions are deprecated and should not be used. They will eventually be removed from the language entirely. To check if a word contains another word, just use `strpos`.

Your logic is also wrong for what you appear to be doing. You need to not overwrite the values of `$intruder` in each iteration of the loop. Set it to 0 before the loop, set it to 1 if there's a match in the loop, then after the loop is complete you'll know if there was a match during any of the comparisons and can print the appropriate message.

```
$found = 0;
foreach ($check as $var) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $var) === 0) {
        $found= 1; 
    }
}

if ($found == 1) {
    echo "You are in my list.";
} else {
    echo "You are not in my list.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? This is the same as the top answer, but was written minutes earlier. I smell vote rigging.

Comment: Your initial answer missed the double equals, that might've been why people downvoted. However, I didn't downvote you :)

Comment: I didn't downvote either. I guess when people visited this Q, my answer was in better shape, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

`if ($intruder = 0);`

To this:

```
if ($intruder == 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

First error:

```
if ($intruder = 0);
```

fix it in this way:

```
if ($intruder == 0)
   echo 'bugger off';
else
   echo 'welcome';
```

Second error:

The use of ereg is deprecated. Replace it with preg_match(); http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: thanks but the problem with your first correction is `<?php $check = array ("85.49.","85.62."); foreach($check as $var) { if (ereg($var, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) { $intruder = 0; } else { $intruder = 1; } if ($intruder == 0) echo 'bugger off'; else echo 'welcome'; } ?>` gives me bugger offwelcome

Comment: @user1615434 you know what you are doing or you have no idea?

Comment: and the problem with replacing ereg with preg_match(); is `<?php
$check = array ("85.49.","85.62.");

foreach($check as $var) {
if (preg_match();($var, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
  $intruder = 0; 
  }
else {
  $intruder = 1;
}
if ($intruder == 0)
   echo 'bugger off';
else
   echo 'welcome';
}
?>` gives me a syntax error on line 5

Comment: @user1615434 ok you have no idea :) 1) read documentation 2) read it again 3) maybe another read is needed 4) write some code 5) read the docs again 6) "oh damn"

Answer (score 1):

Friend, please do not be offended, but I'd rather have asked "is there anything *right* in this code?"

```
<?php
$check = array ("85.49.","85.62.");

foreach($check as $var) {
    // Here you use the deprecated ereg instead of preg_match or, better, strpos
    // However, the regular expressions would be wrong - what if 192.85.49.3 comes by?
    if (ereg($var, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $intruder = 0; 
    }
    else {
        $intruder = 1;
    }
    // Here you do not close the foreach, so that the following code gets executed
    // repeatedly

    // Here you place a ; after the if, so the if body is empty and bugger off gets
    // triggered always.

    // Which changes little, since $intruder = 0 is an assignment (use == instead)
    // (see note)
    if ($intruder = 0);
        echo 'bugger off';
    }
    // Anyway, logically "$intruder == 0" means "NOT an intruder", so you are actually
    // telling friends to bugger off and welcome intruders :-)
    else{
        echo 'welcome';
    }
?>
```

Note: it is maybe voodoo programming (I found it on Maguire's 'Writing Solid Code'), but I think you might get into the habit of checking values the other way:

if (0 == $intruder)

This way if you ever drop a = again, it will not create a new statement doing something you wouldn't want, but it will become a syntax error that makes itself immediately visible.

Anyway, the code for what you want should be:

```
<?php
       $check = array ("85.49.","85.62.");

       $matches = false;

       foreach($check as $var)
       {
           if (0 === strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $var))
           {
               $matches = true;
               // There is one match, no sense in checking further
               break;
           }
       }
       if ($matches)
       {
           // He is in our little list - tell him something
           print "You match.";
       }
?>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, it works great, but what can I do if 192.85.49.3 comes by? Use strpos instead of ereg?

Comment: Yes. Actually that was why I did use strpos in my solution (and also because it's faster, even if, for a simple short loop, it shouldn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

Simple yaar.Just edit:

```
if ($intruder == 0);
        echo 'bugger off';
    }
    else{
        echo 'welcome';
    }
```